# i can't reassign an javascript string variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, assign

i have an exercise to write a function take a string as argument and return a string with first letter capitalized each word. But it doesn't work :( and I dont know why.

```
 function titleCase(str) {
  var arr = str.split(" ")
      arr.forEach(e => 
      {
        let a = (e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1))
        e = a
        console.log(e)
      })
      console.log(arr)
      return arr.join(" ")
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't change the array. You need `map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toUppoerCase doesn't update inplace. That means it doesn't update the source string. You can do something like this using map,

```js
 function titleCase(str) {
  var arr = str.split(" ")
      let res = arr.map(e => 
      {
        let a = (e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1))
        e = a
        console.log(e)
        return e;
      })
      console.log(res)
      return res.join(" ")
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map instead of foreach and return the value in the map.

You can also directly run map after split and you don't have to use `e = a`

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var arr = str.split(" ").map(e => {
    e = (e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1))
    return e;
  })
  return arr.join(" ")
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Or the shorted version

```js
const titleCase = str => str.split(" ").map(e => e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1)).join(" ");
console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't change the array. You need `map`.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var arr = str.split(" ").map(e => 
      {
        let a = (e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1))
        e = a
        console.log(e)
        return e
      })
      console.log(arr)
      return arr.join(" ")
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same function browser console.

```js
    function titleCase(str) {
   var newStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
   for (let i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
       newStr[i] = newStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newStr[i].substring(1);     
   }
   return newStr.join(' '); 
}
console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

**Output**: I'm A Little Tea Pot

Happy Coding!

Comment: OP wants a capitalized string, not all upper case. _"Capitalization ... is writing a word with its first letter as a capital letter (uppercase letter) and the remaining letters in lower case"_ [Capitalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization)

Comment: Thanks Thomas sablik. I have changed logic for the same. Please have a look.

Comment: As you can see in your output `I'M` is not correctly capitalized. OP splits the string by spaces and capitalizes the first letter. You shouldn't change the behavior of OP's code. Just fix the problem.

Comment: Done the changes. Problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

We have to use map() instead of forEach().

First using split() to convert sentences into array of words.

Using map() to capitalize the first character of the word and the rest of the characters of the word into lowercase.

Finally using join() to convert array of words to string.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  const words = str
    .split(" ")
    .map((word) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase());
  return words.join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```